# html css custom div setup

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create some div setup shown in the image attached but not sure how to do so given my basic knowledge:

[image]

Help is greatly appreciated. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use grid and flex box system together for this task.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  
  background: black;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;  
  margin:5px;
}
.row {  
  margin: 5px;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;    
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="box">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="box">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="box">
        5
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        6
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="box">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="box">
        1
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        2
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Malik Lowey - This is perfect exactly what I need, I was havinga  problem when I tried previously adding textareas to field 6 and 2 (last field in sub container 2) and if user decides to expand the textarea it would overlap the main container instead of expand the main container but with what you have provided I just tried and now does exactly what I wanted. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```css
.grid-two-columns{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  
}

.main{
  height: 500px;
  width:500px;
  background-color: white;
}

.sub-container{
  height: 350px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px
}

.two-fields{
  height:50px;
  background-color:yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px
}

.field{
  background-color:green;
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="grid-two-columns">
   <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="grid-two-columns two-fields">
      <div class="field" >
      </div>
      <div class="field" > 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-two-columns two-fields">
      <div class="field" >
      </div>
      <div class="field" > 
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="grid-two-columns two-fields">
      <div class="field" >
      </div>
      <div class="field" > 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-two-columns two-fields">
      <div class="field" >
      </div>
      <div class="field" > 
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```